# Как сделать два @bot.callback_query_handler чтобы они обрабатывали каждую фунцию отдельно

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, telebot, callback

У меня есть две функции **get_promo** и **get_calc** мне нужно чтобы **@bot.callback_query_handler** обрабатывали каждую фунцию отдельно.Снизу освещены данные функции и соответствующие обработчики к ним. Но почему-то когда дело доходит до обработчика функции никаких действий не выполняет. В чем может быть проблема ???

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['promo'])
def get_promo(message):
    if auth(message.chat.id):
        # кнопки
        keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

        # почергово готуєм текст і обробник для кожної кнопки. виводим кнопки на екран
        for promo_code in PromoCode.objects.filter(is_active=True):
            key_gift_code = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                text=promo_code.alias, callback_data=f'promo_code__{promo_code.id}'
            )
            keyboard.add(key_gift_code)
        # показуєм всі кнопки і відображаєм текс
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='Вибирай промо', reply_markup=keyboard)

    else:
        bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            f'Доступ обмежено.\nТвій ID: {message.chat.id} \nЗверністься до адміністратора @den4ik.zim з своїм чат ід'
        )


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'promo_code')

def callback_worker_promo(call):
    # global USER_NUM1, USER_NUM2, A, B

    try:
        model_type, object_id = call.data.split("__")
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Отримано невірні дані.')
        return None

    #if model_type in ['promo_code', '1']:
    try:
        promo_code = PromoCode.objects.get(id=int(object_id))
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, promo_code.code)  # виводим текс у тг.

    except PromoCode.DoesNotExist:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Такого промокода не існує!')


# функція старту розрахунку продукта
@bot.message_handler(commands=['calc'])
def get_calc(message):
    if auth(message.chat.id):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove(selective=False)

        msg = bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            f'Привіт, {message.from_user.first_name}, я почнемо рахувати \nВведіть суму кредиту',
            reply_markup=markup
        )
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_num1_step)
    else:
        bot.send_message(
            message.chat.id,
            f'Доступ обмежено.\nТвій ID: {message.chat.id} \nЗверністься до адміністратора @den4ik.zim з своїм чат ід'
        )


# алогоритм розрахунку позики
# функція записує в глобальну зміну цифру отриману від користувача
def process_num1_step(message, user_result=None):
    try:
        global USER_NUM1

        # запам'ятовуєм число
        # якщо тільки почали /розрахунок
        if user_result is None:
            USER_NUM1 = int(message.text)
        else:
            # якщо результат був переданий раніше
            # пишим перше число, не запитуючи
            USER_NUM1 = int(user_result)

        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введіть кількість днів")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_num2_step)

    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Це не число або щось пілшло не так...')


# отримання 2 числа
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def process_num2_step(message):
    try:
        global USER_NUM2

        # запам'ятовуємо число
        USER_NUM2 = int(message.text)
        # генерація списка продуктів
        message.text = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Почнемо рахувати")
        keyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

        for product in Product.objects.all():
            key_product = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(
                text=product.name, callback_data=f'product__{product.id}'
            )
            keyboard.add(key_product)

        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text="Вибери продукт", reply_markup=keyboard)

    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Це не число або щось пілшло не так...')


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'product')
def callback_worker_calc(call):
    global USER_NUM1, USER_NUM2, A, B
    try:
        model_type, object_id = call.data.split("__")
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Отримано невірні дані.')
        return None

    if model_type == 'product':
        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(id=int(object_id))
        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Такого продукту не існує!')
            return None

        user_result = (USER_NUM1 * product.value) * USER_NUM2 + USER_NUM1
        user_proc = USER_NUM1 * product.value
        user_proc_in_full_time = USER_NUM1 * product.value * USER_NUM2
```

Comment: Переведите заголовок вопроса

Comment: Да и текст вопроса подправить бы - трудно понять, что такое "обродникы" )))

Comment: @vp_arth теперь поставленные вопросы внятно?

Comment: @SergBocharov теперь можешь подсказать что здесь не так ?

Comment: у вас call.data - не 'promo_code' и не 'product', судя по split в теле обработчика

Comment: @vp_arth если смотреть по спит мы получаем **['promo_code', '1']**

Comment: Но лямбда в декораторе ждёт точное совпадение)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте startswith:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith('promo_code'))    
def callback_worker_promo(call):
    pass

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith('product'))
def callback_worker_calc(call):
    pass
```

Comment: да Вы чертов гений, Спасибо!!!